# how to create sealed classes for a list used in two classes

Tags: c#, csvhelper

1. I have a doubt in implementing sealed classes for a list shared by two classes. Suppose Addresses list class is used in multiple classes. How can we define its sealed class when data is coming in two different indexes.
   We have handled class entities by using references, So it is following the hierarchy for getting the sealed classes mapping. But in case of list, it will look for the sealed classes pointing to class Addresses. but I would like to create two separate sealed classes giving two different indexes.

Is there any way to handle lists used in two separate classes.

```
sealed class CSVFileClientMap : CsvHelper.Configuration.CsvClassMap<Client>
{
    public CSVFileClientMap()
    {
        Map(m => m._id).Index(6).Default(null);
        References<CSVFileClientPersonMap>(m=>m.Person);
        Map(m => m.Address).ConvertUsing(row => new List<Addresses> { row.GetRecord<Addresses>() });
    }
}
```

Comment: It is very unclear to me what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @earloc : I want to use separate mapping for the same list used in two different classes. If I use convertusing to  take it as list then I have to define Register.ClassMap<CSVFileClientMap> and it will map the data given in the indexes but we need to register one more mapping class because of different indexes. For say if we create another sealed class CsvFilePersonMap. So whichever sealed class is mapped in the last will overwrite the mapping of first sealed class.